# How to correctly select the children of an updated element in a d3 join?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm struggling to keep d3 selections correct during a data update.

I have a series of nodes that I am manipulating in d3. I want to label them so I have made each node a group that contains the node itself and a text label. The svg structure I'm creating is:

```
<svg>
    <g class="container">
        <g class="node-group">
            <circle class="node">
            <text class="label">
        </g>
        <g class="node-group">
            ...
        </g>
        ...
     </g>
</svg>
```

I am able to do the initial data join.

```
var map_svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var container = map_svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "container");
var node_group = container.selectAll(),
    node = node_group.selectAll(),
    label = node_group.selectAll();

// Initial data join
node_group = node_group.data(graph.nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "node-group");
node = node_group.append("circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("r", 12);

label = node_group.append("text")
                .attr("class", "node-label")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.name
                });
```

After the join I still have access to the `node_group`, `node` and `label` vars with the correct elements and `parentNode`. My problem comes when I do an update - I lose the `parentNode` for the `node` and `label` selections.

```
// Update nodes with new data
var node_group_update = node_group.data(graph.nodes);
var node_group_new = node_group_update.enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node-group");
node_group_update.exit().remove();
node_group_new.append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("r", 12);

node_group_new.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "label")
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.name
                    });

node_group = node_group_update;

// Try to reconstruct the node and label vars, but they don't turn out
// correct because the parentNode is 'html' rather than 'g'
node = d3.selectAll('.node');
label = d3.selectAll('.label');
```

How can I make it so that after the update `node` is the selection of all the nodes with the correct `parentNode`? Can I do it without using a selectAll?

Comment: `node = container.selectAll('.node');` ...

Comment: Thank you for this! Sorry for missing the duplicate question.